# gcc: Linking an External Library

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction

In program.c, I would like to use a method 'avcodec_register_all()' defined in libavcodec/avcodec.h.

Running

```
gcc program.c -L$HOME/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a -L$HOME/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.a
```

Gives me an error

```
/tmp/ccNeQywU.o: In function `main':
program.c:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `avcodec_register_all'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Spelling is correct and the function is defined. Why is this happening?

**program.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int args, char *argv[])
{
 avcodec_register_all();
}
```

Comment: Try `-L$HOME/ffmpeg/lib/ -lavfilter -lavcodec`

Comment: Named, That gave me about 1000 undefined reference errors.

Comment: is `avcodec_register_all` one of them? or is that error gone now?

Comment: avcodec_register_all undefined reference error is gone, but I have undefined reference errors for other methods.

Comment: Then look for the libraries where those functions are defined in and add them the same way.

Comment: Right. All of those functions are defined in the library. Why does compiler say they are undefined?

Comment: Can you update your question with exactly the command you are using and part of the error messages you are getting. and any other relevant info.

Comment: That's how program.c look like. I just call the function defined in the static library. The error message that I'm getting after using -lavfilter -lavcodec is still the same.

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to compile? What is the error you are getting? it can't be the same because you just said earlier that `avcodec_register_all` error is gone now.

Answer (score 4):

It is like this

```
gcc -static -lavfilter -lavcodec -L/HOME/ffmpeg/lib/
```

You need to include the file `avcodec.h` and also add the path to that file in your include path flags to gcc.

```
gcc -static -lavfilter -lavcodec -L$HOME/ffmpeg/lib/ -I$HOME/ffmpeg/include
```

The static is given because your are trying to use a *.a library and not *.so (dynamic).

Comment: Running 'gcc -lavfilter -lavcondec -L/$HOME/ffmpeg/lib/ -I/$HOME/ffmpeg/include program.c' gives me '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavcondec
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status'

Comment: I had a typo as well, I used avcondec when is avcodec, sorry

Comment: Running 'gcc -static -lavfilter -lavcodec -L/$HOME/ffmpeg/lib/ -I/$HOME/ffmpeg/include program.c' gives 'undefined reference to `avcodec_register_all''

Comment: check edit again, please add the `include "avcodec.h"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `-lavcodec` with the existing parameters to gcc

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons may be that the function `avcodec_register_all()` is defined in a C++ file. It should be defined as `extern "C"` in `avcodec.h` and the library should be compiled with this proper `avcodec.h`.

Comment: In this case, the function is defined in C.